# .on() event handler not firing from within div body function

Tags: jquery

Click Event Handler is not firing - I'm sure I'm missing something but it seems to look ok to me? I have also tried `$(document).on('click', '#p_cancel', function() {` with no luck. using JQuery 1.9 so `.on` and `.click` should both work? `div#store_product_div` is a top level div in the document body.

EDIT:
here is https://jsfiddle.net/xzt1krqn/

```js
$('div#store_product_div').on('click', '#p_cancel', function() {
  alert('clicked the p_cancel');
  $(this).parent().parent().hide();
});
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.9.0/jquery.min.js"></script>

<div id="store_product_div">
  <form class="form" action="insert_products.php" id="form_product" method="POST">
    <img src="images/button_cancel.png" class="img" id="p_cancel" />
    <h3>Store Products</h3>
    <hr/><br/>
    <label>Product Name: <span>*</span></label>
    <br/>
    <input type="text" id="p_name" placeholder="Product Name" name="product" />
    <br/>
    <label>Rate: <span>*</span></label>
    <br/>
    <input type="text" id="p_rate" placeholder="Sales Price $" name="rate" /><br/>
    <br/>
    <label>Cost: <span>*</span></label>
    <br/>
    <input type="text" id="p_cost" placeholder="Cost" name="cost" /><br/>
    <br/>
    <label>Taxable: <span>*</span></label>
    <br/>
    <input type="text" id="p_tax" placeholder="Taxable" name="taxable" /><br/>
    <br/>
    <label>Description: <span>*</span></label>
    <br/>
    <input type="text" id="p_desc" placeholder="Description" name="desc" /><br/>
    <br/>

    <input type="submit" id="send" value="Store Product" /><br/>
  </form>
</div>
```

Comment: If you haven't already, have a read of [mcve].  @Qirel has kindly converted your code to a working snippet to "demonstrate the problem" - unfortunately, it demonstrates that the code works absolutely fine and there's no problem.  Please update the snippet to provide code that demonstrates the problem.

Comment: What does your console say? Running the code snippet here on SO seems to work.

Comment: Have you tried using `$('#store_product_div')` instead of `$('div#store_product_div')` as it looks like you're using the id as the selector?

Comment: Try this in your console: `console.log($('div#store_product_div').length, $("#p_cancel").length)` - if either are not `1` then your problem is the selector.

Comment: Also, where are you calling your code?  If it's not in doc.ready then `$(document).on('click', '#p_cancel', function() {` would be a working option (assuming it's after the jquery include).

Comment: @freedomn-m I get nothing in the console but the div form opens ? I have the `console.log($('div#store_product_div').length, $("#p_cancel").length)` at the end of `$(document).ready(function()`   and yes its in the doc ready

Comment: the code snippet fails

Comment: Not sure what you mean by "the code snippet fails".  It shows an alert and then hides the surrounding form, which is exactly what your code (in the question) tells it to.   I had a look at your fiddle, but there's so much code I couldn't (quickly/easily) see how to show `store_product_div` so that the `x` could be clicked.  Have a read of [mcve].

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Why not use:

```
$('#p_cancel').on('click', function() {
    alert('clicked the p_cancel');
    $(this).parent().parent().hide();
});
```

Also, avoid using .parent() and .child(). If you change the HTML structure, you must also change the javascript accordingly.

Comment: This won't work if `p_cancel` is adding dynamically.  OP doesn't state either way, but is already using event delegation, so it's a distinct possibility that this may be the case.

Comment: seems I had a syntax problem that was preventing it from firing, this answer best fixes the problem and get desired results... thanks so much!

Answer (score 1):

You can use closest function of jQuery.

**JQuery**

```
$(function(){
$(document).on('click', '#p_cancel',function() {
   $(this).closest('#store_product_div').hide();
});
});
```

If this code is not working, check your console for checking the error. May be the error is something else.